# How to convert model.fit() to pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, model-fitting

Looking for a precisely equivalent implementation of keras's model.fit() originally in TF to be run in Pytorch. Need to replicate all details of model.fit().
Any formal version already implemented?

[This is the Keras source.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1099-L1472)

Comment: How about pytorch-lighting?

Comment: there is very big difference from the keras api compared to pytorch, i would suggest how pytorch builds and move the model and data to gpu. Pytorch Lighting does a lot for you, but at the end of the day you still need to understand pytorch